Existence of matching of free and interaction fields
When using the interaction picture in QFT to describe a field with a Hamiltonian $H = H_0 + V$, where $H_0$ is the free Hamiltonian, there is a crucial step in which we assume that at some time $t_0$ there is a matching of the free and Heisenberg picture fields. This is important as it allows us to relate the Heisenberg and free fields ($\phi$ and $\phi_0$ respectively) through the equation (see QFT by Schwatz)
$$
\phi(x,t) = U^\dagger(t,t_0)\phi_0(x,t_0)U(t,t_0), \tag{7.32}
$$
where $U(t,t_0) = e^{i H_0 (t-t_0)}S(t,t_0)$ and $S$ satisfies
$$
i\partial_t S(t,t_0)=S(t,t_0)H(t).\tag{7.31}
$$
My question is, how do we justify the assumption that there exists a $t_0$ such that $\phi(t_0)=\phi_0(t_0)$?

It is a conventional choice.

@Qmechanic How so?

Remember that you can have any initial state, which is just a vector in Hilbert space, independent of what H is.  What will be different is how that state evolves in time, which does depend on H. In scattering experiments that initial state is not a bad assumption, as the particles are initially far away and V is negligible.

I see, thank you
